# Método se detiene al pulsar en el back button

Tags: android, android-fragment, geolocalización, back-button

Estoy creando una app en android y utilizo el método `requestLocationUpdates` en un *fragment*, todo me funciona bien pero cuando presiona el *back button* para salir de la app el método `requestLocationUpdates` se detiene. Por favor, ¿alguien podría decirme cómo puedo evitar esto?

Éste es el código que tengo:

```
private void myLocation(){  
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 180000, 0, locationListener);                                  
    getCurrentLocation(location);               
}                                                           

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

     @Override
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         getCurrentLocation(location);
     }                                                                       
}  


Error:  
07-26 10:50:54.450 17918-17918/com.busitec.newhamself E/ViewSystem: ViewRootImpl. #2 Surface is not valid.
07-26 10:56:40.800 24000-24000/com.busitec.newhamself E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.busitec.newhamself, PID: 24000
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
at com.busitec.newhamself.FragmentsIntro.FirstFragment$1.run(FirstFragment.java:37)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Tu pregunta sería más correcta si añades el código donde tienes el problema.

Comment: Al desarrollar en Android es importante el uso del LogCat para encontrar rapida y sencillamente el problema, que mensaje de error se despliega?

Comment: No puedo copiar todo el error en este comentario porque excede la cantidad de caracteres, alguna idea de cómo puedo ponerlo?

Comment: Agrega el mensaje de error a la pregunta.

Comment: Ya lo hice, espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Jhan aún tienes este problema?? si es así agrega tu clase FirstFragment